# Gemspec failing

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm developing a GEM for my graduation final project and Travis CI build is failing constantly.

This is my link on Travis: https://travis-ci.org/ricardobond/perpetuus/builds/8709218

The error on the build is:

```
$ bundle exec rake
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'default'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command "bundle exec rake" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Below is my `perpetuus.gemspec`

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'perpetuus/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "perpetuus"
  spec.version       = Perpetuus::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["Ricardo Caldeira"]
  spec.email         = ["ricardo.nezz@gmail.com"]
  spec.description   = %q{A continuous deploy GEM}
  spec.summary       = %q{Built on top of Ruby on Rails}
  spec.homepage      = ""
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.3"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake"
end
```

And here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in perpetuus.gemspec
gemspec

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec", "~> 2.13"
end
```

Any tips?

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 on Mac OS and RVM 1.19.1

Comment: O do you have `.travis.yml` file in your project root directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have a default task configured in your `Rakefile`. If you want Travis to run your test suite you should probably add something like this in your Rakefile:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
task :default => :spec
```

You can test this configuration locally by running `rake` in your project dir.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the default task in your `Rakefile`

Assuming that you usually run

```
rake test
```

To run your specs, just add this at the end of the file:

```
task :default => [:test]
```

---

You could in theory edit `.travis.yml` instead and give it something other to run than just `rake`:

```
script: "bundle exec rake spec:travis"
```

. . . but adding a default Rake task is easier.